# Textures dissapear in GLES1 on some devices

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine, textures

I am developing a game on Andengine GLES1. I use 8 BitmapTextureAtlases 1024x1024.
On most devices, everything works fine. But on some devices (on HTC desire S and LG P540)
some textures disappear during a game, some textures flicker. Why this happened and how is it to fix?Have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the Engine, try tweaking the options like this:

```
engineOptions.getRenderOptions().disableExtensionVertexBufferObjects();
engine = new Engine(engineOptions);
```

I had the same problem (textures disappeared during execution) and this solved it.

Comment: OMG, been looking to solve this problem on my HTC Desire S forever. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I think its because of very big size of BitmapTextureAtlas. Try to reduce its size and try again.

Comment: I reduced the size of images. Now I have 6 atlases. Glitch was much smaller, but they are there is. You can solve the problem as something different?